# Is there a way to compare each row with each column and increment the values depending on each case in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

This is what my current df looks like. I constructed it by reading in a textile and pivoting it so the the strings/vocabId are my rows and the word/fortuneId are my rows.

```
df = pd.read_csv('combine.txt')
 
df=df.pivot(index='fortuenId',columns='vocabId',values='ratings').fillna(0)
```

is there a way to compare each fortuneId with each vocabId? For example, comparing "feature", from the fortuneId, and "the feature is blue" on the vocabId. Since the word "feature" is in my string, "the feature is blue", I increment the 0 to 1.

I have tried following this tutorial, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterating-over-rows-and-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/

```
for key, value in df.iteritems():
        print(key, value)
```

This prints out
[image]

When I print out the key, it outputs the strings. When I print the value, it prints out the words with the ratings. How can I access the ratings/0.0 itself and then increment if needed?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way, but this is how I updated the value

```
for key, value in df.iteritems():
    i=1
   # print(value)
    for name,val in value.iteritems():
        i=i+1
       # print("the name, ",name, " the val is ",val," the key is ",key)
        if name in key:
            print("the name is ",name, "the key is ", key)
            val=1+val
           # df.at[i,'vocabId']=1
            df.loc[name,key]=1
```